# How to structure different types of a model in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am building an application where users can apply for small business loans. There are 4 types of loans (A,B,C,D). There are 10 commons questions no matter which type they choose, but then based on which type of loan they want, there are 3-4 more questions specific for that type.

What is the best way to represent this in the database?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Consider having all questions in a single table.  Have a column that is datatype `SET` with (currently) 4 "bits":  `'A','B','C','D'`.  10 questions would have all 4 bits set; the others would have one bit each.

(There are certainly other ways to solve this.)

Answer (score 0):

For flexibility, I would have a many-to-many relationship between loan types and questions:

- `questions(question_id, question, ...)`
- `loan_types(loantype_id, more field...)`
- `loan_type_questions(loantypw_id, question_id, [order, other fields])`

This way will allow you to

- add more features later if needed. For example, depending on the loan type, you want the questions to show in a specific order. For this, you add `order` field in the relation table.
- Add more question and/or loan types without having to modify the structure of the tables.

Again, as Rick mentioned, there are other, maybe better, ways :)